# Getting events based on 2 date meta keys in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, events, custom-fields

I am using Custom Fields and Post Types to create some events type posts in WP. Each event (post type: events) contains following fields:

- Title (the_title)
- Description (the_content)
- Start Date (meta_key: start_date) stores timestamp in meta_value
- End Date (meta_key: end_date) stores timestamp in meta_value

**What I want is,** to get all records which fall between dates. For example, I want to show a calendar (month view). I want to query for all such events which are/may occur in a particular month.

**The main problem is,** if events are of single date (same day) or a short range (same month, spanning a few days) or short range between adjacent months (a few days, but dates ranging between April 2013 and May 2013, suppose) all works fine. BUT, when an event spans across months, like if an event starts at 20th April 2013 and ends at 25th July 2013, it doesn't show up. It only visible in April 2013 and July 2013 - while I want to display this on all occurring months (April'13, May'13, June'13 and July'13).

Can anyone help me build a WP's custom query (**WP_Query or direct MySQL query on Posts and Posts Meta tables**) to resolve this issue? Remember there are 2 meta fields (as mentioned above), which store start and end dates in time-stamps.

-- Edit --

For an insight of what I am using currently, following is the SQL query I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    wpmh_posts.* 
FROM 
    wpmh_posts, wpmh_postmeta 
WHERE 
    wpmh_posts.ID = wpmh_postmeta.post_id 
    AND wpmh_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wpmh_posts.post_type = 'events_calendar' 
    AND ( 
            ( 
                (
                    wpmh_postmeta.meta_key='wpcf-start_date' 
                    AND wpmh_postmeta.meta_value >= 1364774400
                ) OR (
                    wpmh_postmeta.meta_key='wpcf-end_date' 
                    AND wpmh_postmeta.meta_value >= 1364774400
                ) 
            ) OR ( 
                (
                    wpmh_postmeta.meta_key='wpcf-start_date' 
                    AND wpmh_postmeta.meta_value <= 1367366399
                ) OR (
                    wpmh_postmeta.meta_key='wpcf-end_date' 
                    AND wpmh_postmeta.meta_value <= 1367366399
                ) 
            ) 
    ) 
    ORDER BY 
        wpmh_postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

Where 1364774400 is a timestamp for April 1st, 2013 and 1367366399 is a timestamp for April 30th, 2013 (obviously containing times 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 respectively). But I don't want to compare times, I simply want to pick all those records falling between these 2 timestamps, even the event's start date is of previous month's and ending at somewhere next or any upcoming month - which is logically an occurring event for April 2013 also.

For an example of events, I have following events:

- Test Event 1: Starts March 01, 2013 Ends March 10, 2013
- Test Event 2: Starts April 10, 2013 Ends April 26, 2013
- Test Event 3: Starts April 10, 2013 Ends May 05, 2013
- Test Event 4: Starts March 15, 2013 Ends June 10, 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Modified WP_Query below**

Its pretty hard to give you good help if you don't share your own code.

I have used the following code for a custom calendar in WordPress:

```
// Query arguments for upcoming events query
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => strtotime(date("Y-m-d")), // Uses current server timestamp now
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC' // I think you will need to use numeric here, instead of datestamp
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', // Edit: Changed this so its sorted after numeric value
    'meta_key' => 'start_date', // Sort after 'start_date'
    'post_type' => 'events_calendar', // Change this value to your own 'post_type_name'
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

// The Query
$upcoming_events_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $upcoming_events_query->have_posts() ) : $upcoming_events_query->the_post();
    // Your template code here!
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

The posts will be sorted after your start_date, but events which has passed the end date will be excluded from the query.

This will only work if all your events start_date and end_date values are saved as the following date-format: 'Y-m-d' - This query have only been tested on dates, and have not been combined with time in dates. In worst case scenario, this might give you something to build upon.

If you want more help, please share your code.

Comment: Thanks icethrill - it's a pretty good effort. For everyone's convenience, I have added the code and sample events. Please take a look and please help. Thank again.

Comment: Modified my WP_Query so it could possibly suit your needs. Try it out.

Comment: Hey man, your work-around is great, almost near, but I want to narrow it down to just comeup with such events falling in the current month. Your 'end_date' >= the current day returns record such record which are starting in next month as well. I am try to work on your solution more to fix it as I need. I will share with you as well. Meanwhile can you help more around the needed? Thanks in advance and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: No problem mate, try the modified args array (http://pastebin.com/YvZ56LZ8) in the link. Should get events between todays date and the last date in the month. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you icethrill, although your pastebin code didn't resolve the needed, but your previous edit was awsome, I used that. I tried a lot of complex queries, but it seems that based on the nature of custom fields (using the same 2 columns, meta_key and meta_value) for storing different nature of data, was the main issue towards the resolution. However, using your solution and a mix of page template checks, I achieved it. Thanks a lot buddy :)